# How to get parameters using symbolic breakpoints in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

I have a breakpoint that looks like this

```
-[UITableViewCell setSelected:]
```

and it works, but I cannot figure out how to get the value that is being passed in.

I have tried `-[UITableViewCell setSelected:(BOOL)what]` and `-[UITableViewCell setSelected:what]` which do not work at all.

**How can I access the parameters?**

If this doesn't work, I'll have to make a `DebugUITableViewCell` just to see what's going on, which is a hassle and touches a lot of code.

Comment: I'm not brave enough to post this a real answer as I"m just speculating, but I believe want is just not available to the debugger. You don't get the symbols for UIKit so the debugger has no idea about what the name of the argument is to that method. the runtime might be able to figure out its type, but its not the same as having the real symbol information.  Your subclass trick works I guess because you are also providing that symbol info to the debugger.

Comment: I arrived at this question for the exact same method — without even including the method name in the search query. Table views truly are a mystery, and even more so 5 years later! 

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you debug your code on the device the parameters when you hit your breakpoint will consistently be in registers r0, r1, and r2.  If you use `po $r0` you'll see the object receiving setSelected.  If you use `po $r1` you'll get "no Objective-C description available" because that's the selector.  Inspect $r2 to see if selected is being set to YES or NO.  It's a similar story on i386, but I can't remember off hand which registers are used.

Comment: I know this was a well-used trick with gdb, but I believe it will not work consistently in lldb.

Comment: @darren I tested this with lldb before posting my answer, but what makes you think it wouldn't work?

Comment: It will work fine with lldb.  In fact, it's even better in lldb because (for architectures that pass arguments in registers, like arm and x86_64) `$arg0`, `$arg1` etc are provided which alias to the correct register for that architecture.

Comment: Incidentally, for i386 you need to read stack memory based on the stack pointer (if you're on the first instruction of the function/method) to find the arguments.

Comment: Cool. I remember trying this out when LLDB first came out and thought it was not working as i expected. Thanks for confirming it does work as expected.

Comment: @JasonMolenda I thought on i386 some arguments are passed via register, with the rest on the stack?

Comment: The return value from the function is passed in eax IIRC but otherwise all argument passing is on the stack.  If a function is only called from within a single dylib it is possible to use a non-standard ABI that passes args in regs -- I think there may even be a command line option to clang to do this, or at least there was one for gcc in the distant past, but it would be an alternate ABI and any callers would need to know about it.

Comment: In lldb access the arguments starting with $arg1. For a method call the first user argument is $arg3; So if the first method argument is a NSString just `po $arg3` to display it.

Comment: Tried to log a `CGPoint` argument but `p (CGPoint)$arg3` doesn't work.

Comment: I also could not get `po $arg0` to work in lldb. Tried both x86_64 and on arm64.

Comment: po $r2 and po $arg3 is good for the first parameter. But how to get the second parameter, the third parameter

Comment: While debugging in the Xcode 6 iOS Simulator, `$arg1`..etc., were not recognised. But this did work: [Accessing parameters on Intel 32-bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-TABLE2). For example, with a break at `-[CALayer setBackgroundColor:]`, I used a log message action: `[@(NSString*)[((CALayer*)(*(int*)($esp+4))).delegate description]@ setBackgroundColor: @(NSString*)[(id)*(int*)($esp+12) description]@]` and autocontinue - very useful for a tricky problem I had. /cc @stigi @ortwingentz

Comment: [Accessing parameters on ARM](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-TABLE1).

[Accessing parameters on Intel 32-bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-TABLE2).

Comment: @t0rst, What about accessing them in `lldb`?

Answer (score 18):

In LLDB on Simulator use

`p $arg3`

for the first parameter.

Answer (score 6):

You could replace `-[UITableViewCell setSelected:]` with your own implementation for debugging purposes. Below, `UITableViewCellSetSelected` will be called instead of UIKit's method.

```
static void (*__originalUITableViewCellSetSelected)( UITableViewCell *, SEL, BOOL ) ;
static void UITableViewCellSetSelected( UITableViewCell * self, SEL _cmd, BOOL b )
{
    // your code here... (or set a breakpoint here)
    NSLog(@"%@<%p> b=%s\n", [ self class ], self, b ? "YES" : "NO" ) ;

    (*__originalUITableViewCellSetSelected)( self, _cmd, b ) ; // call original implementation:
}

@implementation UITableViewCell (DebugIt)

+(void)load
{
    Method m = class_getInstanceMethod( [ self class ], @selector( setSelected: ) ) ;
    __originalUITableViewCellSetSelected = (void(*)(id, SEL, BOOL))method_getImplementation( m ) ;
    method_setImplementation( m, (IMP)UITableViewCellSetSelected ) ;
}

@end
```

Comment: although for a quick solution @aaron's answer is good. I'll leave this here for info...

Comment: I think I might accept Aaron's answer because it's more on point, but this is great too. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For the methods without source code, the following works: Put a symbolic breakpoint so that the debugger stops at the first line of the method. Make sure the top stack frame is selected. Then:

In Objectice-C methods

- `po $arg1` prints self
- `po $arg3` prints the first argument, remaining arguments in `$arg4`, `$arg5`, etc.

In C functions the arguments start at `$arg1`

This works both on IOS device and simulator.

Comment: `$arg1` etc will only work for 64 bit simulators. For legacy x86 32bit ones that would translate to `x/x $esp4` , `x/x $esp+8` etc See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48734614/5329717

Answer (score 2):

Based on `-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:]` symbol we can add symbolic breakpoint to check which sender has sent an action to which target.

We create symbolic breakpoint with:

- symbol: `-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:]`
- debugger command line actions:

  - `po "Target"`
  - `po $arg4`
  - `po "Sender"`
  - `po $arg5`

The output would be:

`"Target"
<project.TargetViewController: 0x14ddb1470>
"Sender"
<UIButton: 0x14de86000; frame = (331 7; 49 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x174237020>>`

So as @Dan said, method parameters start with argument 3 (`po $arg3`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use lldb command:

"image lookup -rn keyword"

keyword equals functions you wanna search, eg, show

then, you will look some output like follows,

Summary: ApplSlate`closure #2 (__C.UIBarButtonItem) -> () in ApplSlate.BaseTableViewController.showLoading(includeTabBar: Swift.Bool) -> () at BaseTableViewController.swift:98        Address: FullSlate[0x0000000100154a60] (FullSlate.__TEXT.__text + 1378752)

And you get the symbolic name is : `closure #2 (__C.UIBarButtonItem) -> () in ApplSlate.BaseTableViewController.showLoading(includeTabBar: Swift.Bool) -> ()`

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

`Xcode`'s `lldb` get `ObjC` first parameter is: `$arg3`

->

- `lldb` print first parameter value: `po $arg3`

  - [image]
- Xcode add symbolic breakpoint condition: still use `arg3`

  - eg

    - Condition: `(BOOL)($arg3 == NULL)`

      - [image]

### Related

- rest parameter is: `$arg4`, `$arg5`, ...
- `$arg0` not exists

  - eg

    ```
    (lldb) po $arg0
    error: <user expression 3>:1:1: use of undeclared identifier '$arg0'
    $arg0
    ^
    ```
- `$arg1` is function type

  - `-` means `Instance`

    - eg

      ```
      (lldb) po $arg1
      _
      ```
  - `+` means `Class`
- `$arg2` is function pointer self, use `SEL` can parse to function name

  - eg

    ```
    (lldb) po $arg2
    8203662366

    (lldb) po (SEL)$arg2
    "stringByAppendingString:"
    ```

Comment: thanks. does this add new value that's not in the accepted answer?

Comment: I think yes, at least add SOME extra value for `Related` part of my answer, for other (newbie) like me before

Comment: Seems like more of a comment on an answer, but ok. Could you please fix the answer to use `Xcode` (the name of the IDE) instead of `XCode` (common mistake)? Thanks.