# Xcode symbolic breakpoint: print parameters

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I added a symbolic breakpoint on objc_release which has one parameter,
when Xcode breaks on it, how could I print the parameter?

some say register read could print registers, values of r0 r1 are the first and second parameter,
is it true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get parameters using symbolic breakpoints in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513045/how-to-get-parameters-using-symbolic-breakpoints-in-objective-c)