# Breakpoint for "Warning: Attempt to present * on * which is already presenting *"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, breakpoints

Sometimes it happens that - from different places in code - we want to do `UIViewController.presentViewController(a, b, c)`, and sometimes it happens that we are already presenting, in which case we get:

`Warning: Attempt to present * on * which is already presenting *`

Is it possible to break on this warning? How can I set a breakpoint for this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First things first, you need to set a symbolic breakpoint to `-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]`. You can add this easily via Xcode's `Add Symbolic Breakpoint` feature.

Secondly, you need to set a condition so that the breakpoint is hit only when the view controller already presents something. Programatically speaking, this means that the `presentedViewController` property is non-nil. The trick here is to access the `self` implicit parameter passed to any method call, which can be done by using `$arg1` (more details on that  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513045/how-to-get-parameters-using-symbolic-breakpoints-in-objective-c)). Once you have this, the rest is easy.

Here's how the breakpoint should look like:

[image: Breakpoint]
<sub>(source: [cristik-test.info](https://cristik-test.info/presentVC-br.png))</sub>

In summary:

Symbol: `-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]`
Condition: `[(UIViewController *)$arg1 presentedViewController] != nil`

This works for Objective-C as well as Swift projects, since the `UIViewController` is (still) exporting its public methods as Objective-C symbols.

Comment: Right! I was already thinking that I dont want to check the presentedViewController in code everywhere I call presentViewController, and oversaw that I can use that if-check as a condition for the breakpoint. Awesome! Just need to verify that it works.