# URLSession dataTask symbolic breakpoint at specific URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, lldb

I have an API wrapper, which is logging all URLs requested by `URLSession`. I need to breakpoint at specific URL call, for a possibility to easily find a place in UI, from where API call is initialized.

There is no problem to stop at any *URLSession dataTask*. I'm doing this with `lldb` command `br set -F '-[__NSCFURLSessionTask resume]'`:

[image: Adding symbolic breakpoint]

Then the program stops:

[image]

So, the question:

Is there any way to obtain URL from context on the screenshot above, match it with provided URL, and continue if URLs doesn't match?

Or maybe some other ideas (`lldb` python script for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with figuring out the `instance` **pointer** value at the breakpoint.
Since an `Objective-C` `selector` is being sent inside the `Swift` `.resume()` call we must fallback to the actual implementation of:

```
objc_msgSend(receiver, selector, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Without going into too much details we rely on MacOS/iOS ABI specifying which cpu registers are used for passing arguments. We're interested specifically in the 1st argument to find the `receiver instance` **pointer** value.

**Private** class `__NSCFURLSessionTask` happens to have following method:

```
- (NSURL*)currentRequest_URL;
```

@JimIngham pointed out an amazing shortcut to accomplish this with universal argument synonyms being `$arg1 $arg2 ...` in `lldb`. (notice that selector's `arg1 arg2` would be `lldb`'s `$arg3 $arg4` respectively) This simplifies it to:

```
po [$arg1 currentRequest_URL] 
https://www.google.com
```

In case of `x86` `32bit` `Simulator` which would correspond to devices lower than `iPhone 5S` you would use instead:

```
(lldb) x/x $esp+4
     0xbff9e050: 0x7874dd70
(lldb) po [0x7874dd70 currentRequest_URL]
    https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! Now I can probably write a simple lldb python script, to continue execution if URL doesn't match.

Comment: Note that for all the architectures that pass arguments in registers (everything but i386) lldb defines the aliases $arg1, $arg2 to point to the argument passing register for the current architecture.